# I want to run a python script from my HTML website by clicking on button to show the value from script

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have written a Python program to process some data. I want to run that Python program when the user clicks a button, and display the output on the web page. Here is my web page:

```js
function changeText() {
  document.getElementById('boldStuff').textContent = ____________;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="calcscore"> This is your score:
  <b id='boldStuff'>score</b>
</h2>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Click for Score' />
```

My Python program is called `scorecalculator.py` and ends with:

```
print(finalScore)
```

What should I write in my JavaScript to make this work?

(I'm using Flask.)

Comment: Hey, don't downvote so much! I expect this to be a genuinely useful question, once it's been cleaned up a bit. Lots of people are asking this sort of thing and, if not a duplicate, this could be made into a nice canonical question.

Comment: I downvoted because there's no attempt from the user

Comment: @user4343502 That's because (as we both know) no attempt is possible. It would be hard for a new programmer to search for this sort of thing, because it's considered a complex thing and so uses more technical language.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Even though you raise fair points, the question (as written) is too broad to answer and that's a reason for closing/downvoting

Comment: @user4343502 Flask. It's in the tags, though that isn't very clear.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 you can still answer it

Comment: @user4343502 not using jinga, using PyCharm as an IDE and I used flask to get my files uploaded but not sure how to use it for this

Answer (score 0):

You can't run Python on the web page, because you'd have to run the Python program in the user's web browser and no common web browser supports client-side Python.

However, you *can* run the Python on your web server, then send the result back to the web page using the [`WebSockets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) API. By running a web socket server program on your server, you can communicate with the user's copy of the web page. You can then use JavaScript to send the file to the server, and then receive an output value from the user.

To make the web socket server program, you can use a module such as [`websockets`](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) to receive the file, process it, then send the score back to the webpage.

Comment: I am receiving the files from a modal using flask to save onto a server, from there I have a .py file that will call on the most file uploaded to calculate a score.Once I get that final number, I want that to be populated. Should have included that earlier but seemed to complicate the question

Comment: @twitsnatch621 That's a bad way of doing it, because if two people upload a file really close to each other they'll get the same score, but one person's score will be the other person's score instead of their score. Instead, see if you can send the file directly to the program by modifying it to be a web socket server. Instead of `print`ing, send it back to the user.

Comment: @twitsnatch621 If it's unclear how to implement any of this, let me know and I'll improve the answer.

Comment: is there an example of the process you described above that I can reference?

Comment: @twitsnatch621 Do you mean the JavaScript end or the Python end? If you mean the JavaScript end there's this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that allows you to do this. See [skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/).

Python runs in the user browser, so you need to be aware of this - especially, if you have clients that will be using the site.

Caveat Emptor!